# How to use ui:composition in p:TabMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm working on example how to use Primefaces 3.4.1 `p:TabMenu`:

Main page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <div id="settingsHashMapz" class="settingsHashMap" style="width:1150px; height:400px; position:absolute; top:20px; left:1px">

            <p:tabMenu id="tabs" activeIndex="0" >  
                <p:menuitem value="tab1" url="/tab1.jsf" />  
                <p:menuitem value="tab2" url="/tab2.jsf" />  
                <p:menuitem value="tab3" url="/tab3.jsf" />

            </p:tabMenu>  
        </div>   
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Tab 1 page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:form id="tab1" >
                    ................. 
                </h:form>         
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I noticed a problem when I try to use `p:tabMenu`. I cannot use `ui:composition` properly. I have to declare namespaces in every tab page because they cannot use the namespaces from the main JSF page. If I declare all namespaces into the tab pages I have to wait ~3 seconds to transfer Javascript libraries from the server. As you can see it's waste of resources:

```
GET http://server:8080/DCProfileTabGenerators.jsf 200 OK 29ms                              jquery....min.js (line 4)
GET http://server:8080/javax.f...uery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&_=1349526707969 200 OK 11ms   jquery....min.js (line 4)
GET http://server:8080/javax.f.../primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&_=1349526708568 200 OK 8ms   jquery....min.js (line 4)
GET http://server:8080/javax.f...source/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&_=1349526708949 200 OK 8ms   jquery....min.js (line 4)
GET http://server:8080/resources/js/tabs.js?_=1349526709016 200 OK 10ms
```

How I can use the namespaces declared into the main JSF page into the tab JSF pages?

Answer (score 2):

Declaring namespaces at the top of the page does not impart any real performance loss.  It just declares which namespaces you wish to use on a given page file.  In essence there is no real way to do this however it is not necessary.

The GET requests below are for downloading the necessary javascript libraries, stylesheets and images to the client.  Depending on the client browser settings, these should be cached after the first request so that this client will not have to download them multiple times as they navigate pages throughout your application.

Comment: Maybe I can fix the problem using `p:tabMenu` with `ui:insert`?